# (Lucene.Net) Turkish stemmer is causing SnowballProgram to throw an index out of range exception. How to fix it?

Tags: lucene.net, turkish, snowball

Certain words in the Turkish stemmer is causing SnowballProgram to throw an index out of range exception. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Some code sample that shows and reproduces the issue would be really helpful

Comment: I am sorry that I am not able to upload a picture here since I am new in Stackoverflow. However, this issue is present in the following site with details: 

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-544 

I appreciate if you can look at that site and find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Itamar was unable to confirm the error. Can you help by posting a failing test?